Trivialism "inside" a paraconsistent logic?
Trivialism is the view that every contradiction is true and accepts the principle of explosion of inconsistencies
Paraconsistency in turn is an attempt to study contradictions in a controlled way. Paraconsistency accepts some contradictions (but not all contradictions) and takes the principle of non-explosion (similarly to the principle of non contradiction of classical logics) to avoid trivialism
However, if paraconsistent logics "isolate" contradictions to avoid the principle of explosion to study them in a controlled manner, couldn't a paraconsistent system "isolate" a trivialist system to study it with control?

Contradictions can be "isolated" because they are individual statements, trivialism only applies to all statements at once. What exactly are you proposing to "isolate"? If not all statements are both true and false then the system is not trivial. And if they are what is there to study?

Under trivialism, all propositions are true, so there is nothing for logic to do and nothing to study.
